# GraphQL.js - timestamp scalar type?

Tags: javascript, schema, graphql, graphql-js, scalar

I am building a GraphQL schema programmatically and in need of a `Timestamp` scalar type; a [*Unix Epoch timestamp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) scalar type:

```js
const TimelineType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'TimelineType',
  fields: () => ({
    date:  { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLTimestamp)  },
    price: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLFloat)      },
    sold:  { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)        }
  })
});
```

Unfortunately, GraphQL.js **doesn't** have a `GraphQLTimestamp` nor a `GraphQLDate` type so the above doesn't work.

I am expecting a `Date` input and I want to convert that to a timestamp. How would I go about creating my own GraphQL timestamp type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an NPM package with a set of RFC 3339 compliant date/time GraphQL scalar types; [graphql-iso-date](https://github.com/excitement-engineer/graphql-iso-date).

---

But for starters, You should use [`GraphQLScalarType`](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlscalartype) to build your own scalar type in GraphQL programmatically:

```js
/** Kind is an enum that describes the different kinds of AST nodes. */
import { Kind } from 'graphql/language';
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';

const TimestampType = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Timestamp',
  serialize(date) {
    return (date instanceof Date) ? date.getTime() : null
  },
  parseValue(date) {
    try           { return new Date(value); }
    catch (error) { return null; }
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
      return new Date(parseInt(ast.value, 10));
    }
    else if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING) {
      return this.parseValue(ast.value);
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  },
});
```

But instead of re-inventing the wheel, this issue ([#550](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/550)) was already discussed and Pavel Lang came up with a decent [GraphQLTimestamp.js](https://gist.github.com/langpavel/b30f3d507a47713b0c6e89016e4e9eb7) solution (my `TimestampType` is derived from his).